# how to list older R package versions using available.packages

Tags: r, installation, package, version

I have built some R packages (binaries, .RD files, everything), created a CRAN-style local respository, and used the command `write_PACKAGES(..., verbose = TRUE, type = c("source"), subdirs = TRUE, latestOnly = FALSE)` to document it all. It works great and I can use standard CRAN-style commands to access it all.

Using `old.packages` I can see what to update if I have an old version installed and want a new one. However, I would like to go backwards and see what old versions i can install if a newer one is installed. Thius is necessary to access old versions that i used for publication purposes. All versions (old and new) of a package are listed in my PACKAGES file. here is an example:

```
Package: SJMio
Version: 2.0
Depends: R (>= 3.0.0), SJMbase (>= 2.0), digest, formatR
License: file LICENSE
MD5sum: 1f697d15d1d73b90e07728f700882942
NeedsCompilation: no

Package: SJMio
Version: 2.1
Depends: R (>= 3.0.0), SJMbase (>= 2.0), digest, formatR
License: file LICENSE
MD5sum: a223fbdca9c605bdc422436f4013efdd
NeedsCompilation: no
```

Question: why can't i get the command `available.packages` to list versions older than I have installed? Is there another command that can do this? I need to write functions to automate this, and optionally install the older versions, for my dept. at work.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I *think* that if you use an appropriate version of the `filter` argument such as `filter=c("R_version", "OS_type", "subarch")` you might get multiple versions? (But I don't seem to be getting this to work.)

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes, I thought this too.  I tried the filter="duplicates" option, which should be the correct command.  But I could not get it to work either. The command is accepted (i.e. no error), but no different results either.

Comment: Many years later, I also can't get `available.packages()` with filters to work as I'd expect based on the documentation. Have tried on 3.4 and 4.0. I even tried wiping the temp cache it creates